# Android-Last item of the ListView is not visible

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have added the ListView inside ViewPager, as soon as the page is loaded the first tab is selected and the last item of the list does not show up for the first time, its becoming visible when I go to next tab and come back. I would like to see all the items of the listview when its loaded for the first time. Please help me to fix this problem.

This is the xml for the listview -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_categories"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@color/light_gray_a1"
    android:dividerHeight="0.667dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_Parent`

Comment: Adding match_parent did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

add bottom padding like this and change fill_parent to match_parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/light_gray_a1"
    android:dividerHeight="0.667dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. Just now I solved it. Look for `android:layout_weight` in all the Layouts you used and if it is set some non zero values like `android:layout_weight="1"` or `android:layout_weight="0.91"`, then set them to zero like this,

`android:layout_weight="0"`